# How to install Gridsome: zsh: command not found: gridsome

Tags: gridsome

I'm attempting to create a new `Gridsome` project and continually receive the following message in the terminal:

`zsh: command not found: gridsome`

**Steps I've taken**

(https://gridsome.org/docs/)

1. `npm install --global @gridsome/cli`
2. `cd testProjects`
3. `gridsome create my-gridsome-site`

At this point i receive the error and cannot seem to find a way to resolve it.

Comment: Try adding `~/.npm_global/bin` and `~/.npm-packages/bin` to PATH.

Comment: Hey @shamilpython - Are you able to provide an answer with the specifics of how to do that and what it achieves please? (Not entirely sure what it'll do) Thanks! :)

Comment: hey @Que did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using `yarn` for installation. So simply run the following commands :

1. Install yarn. On Mac OS do it using homebrew. `brew install yarn`.
2. cd to place where you would like your project to be, and then run `gridsome create my-gridsome-site`.

However, not sure why installing with `npm`, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

if you install globally like this `yarn global add @gridsome/cli`

you need to add this on your path in .zshrc if you use zsh

```
~/.yarn/bin
```

here's my .zshrc config in the last line, focus on the GLOBAL one

```
export TWEEGO=$HOME/DEV/TWINE/tweego
export ANDROID_SDK=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export GLOBAL=$HOME/.yarn/bin
export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK/emulator:$ANDROID_SDK/tools:$TWEEGO:$GLOBAL:$PATH
```